# Flutter_webview_plugin net::err_unknown_url_scheme. error while opening external apps

Tags: flutter, webview, android-webview, flutter-test, flutterwebviewplugin

Flutter_webview_plugin

But in my website there is a button which open whatsapp app and other apps

But in my webview after clicking that button it shows this error with all external app

Can you solve this
[this image will show the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IeRb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this and replace tel,mailto: and whatsapp with your external app links starting string.

`  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
  if (url.startsWith('mailto:'))
  {

    _launchURL(url);
    flutterWebviewPlugin.stopLoading();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.reload();



  }
  else if (url.startsWith('tel:'))
  {

    _launchURL(url);
    flutterWebviewPlugin.stopLoading();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.reload();


  }else if (url.startsWith('whatsapp:') ||url.startsWith ('api.'))
  {

    _launchURL(url);
    flutterWebviewPlugin.stopLoading();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.reload();


  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull("whatsapp://send?phone=+966${phone}");

await _launchWhatsapp(encoded);


_launchWhatsapp(String url){

final  url: Uri.parse(url);
}
```

make sure you you are using whatsapp: scheme